# why am I getting NSRangeException in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to load a plist from my project, this was working until I accidentally deleted my plist. the plist has 5 arrays, with 2 elements apiece. I know that I the program is trying to access beyond the range of the array, but what I don't know is where this index is set? Here is the code that it bombs on: this code is executed twice successfully,then for some reason it tries to access it a third time and bombs on the first line,why?

It throws this exception:

```
NSRangeException -[_NSCFARRAY objectAtIndex] index(2) beyond bounds (2)
```

please help, this is for a final project due on Monday and now I feel like I have to start over again.

```
 NSString *nameOfAccount = [account objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text = nameOfAccount;
 NSString *accountNumber = [number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = accountNumber;
```

Comment: Since you are using two arrays for getting name and account, while giving the number of rows you might have given the count of either one of them. If by any chance their count differs this is error can happen. If you can share the structure of your plist, you can modify your code to remove this error.

Comment: show your "`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`" data source method;

Comment: thanks and I do agree with you, oddly enough though, I added more elements to each of the arrays and now it is working again. I don't understand how that matters. so now each of the 5 arrays have equally 5 corresponding elements.

Comment: Good to know that it's working, but there is some issue in the way you are handling your dataSource.

Comment: Why not you are using single array of dictionaries. Because in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method before return you have to compare all array first to have same number of object.

Comment: I was in a tutorial that I went through that had me building the plist with arrays, for a Master/detail view template. if you have a better suggestion, I would love to hear it. Thank you

Comment: I have given an answer, you can check it out.

Comment: thank you for this... I am pretty new so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are displaying the data in same cell, you can include both name and number of account into a dictionary or a custom model object which will hold both info.

In your plist this might be the structure, array of dictionary objects

[image]

When you are displaying the info. For the dataSource create an array say `accounts`.

```
#define kAccountName @"Name"
#define kAccountNumber @"Number"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Accounts" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.accounts = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.accounts count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *account = self.accounts[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = account[kAccountName];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = account[kAccountNumber];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

[Source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestTwoDataSourceTV.zip)